# Inverse element over integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've read that the inverse elements over integers exist only for -1 and 1.

1. Why is that?
2. What is the inverse of -1?

Comment: inverse of -1 is -1. suppose $a$ is an integer its inverse is $\frac{1}{a}$ which isnot integer.

Comment: inverse of integer $n$ must be an *integer* $m$ with $nm=1$. Then $1$ and $-1$ are the only integers that have inverses: $1.1=1$ and $(-1)(-1)=1$. Just try to find one e.g. for $2$. You will get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inverse of $0$. If $n>1$ then, for every $m\ne0$,
$$
|nm|=n\,|m|\ge n>1
$$
so certainly $nm\ne1$; we conclude that $n$ has no inverse. Similarly if $n<-1$.

Thus only $1$ and $-1$ remain. Since
$$
1\cdot 1=1,\qquad
(-1)\cdot(-1)=1
$$
the inverse of $1$ is $1$ and the inverse of $-1$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because if $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{-1,1\}$, there does not exist $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $nm=1$
2. The inverse of $-1$ is $-1$ as $(-1)\times (-1)=1$.